# Change Custom word from anchor tag href attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I Transfer my website from www.guruji.com/demo to guruji.com

now my all links is  `<a href="www.guruji/demo/index.php">home</a>` `<a href="www.guruji/demo/about.php">about</a>`

i want to remove demo from all link

how can i do this Please Solve

Comment: What is your website built with? can you also paste some code that controls the navigation?

Comment: If links are hard coded `Ctrl+H`  => replace `/demo/` by an empty string ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('a').each(function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    url = url.replace("demo/", '');
    $(this).attr('href', url);
})
```

This basically says loop over every a tag, take the href value, remove the demo/ part, and replace it with url.

The ctrl+H method suggested by Flo is easier imo